# How to get the updateTime for a "directory" blob using the GCS Java APIs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a "directory" that I've created in my Google Cloud Storage bucket.  I can list it using gsutil, and I see associated times:

```
>gsutil ls -L gs://mybucket/Dir2/
gs://mybucket/Dir2/:
    Creation time:          Thu, 11 Feb 2021 19:15:32 GMT
    Update time:            Thu, 11 Feb 2021 19:15:32 GMT
    Storage class:          STANDARD
    Content-Length:         0
    ...
TOTAL: 1 objects, 0 bytes (0 B)
```

In my Java code, I am trying to retrieve the update time, but the updateTime (and the createTime) show up in the blob as being null.  Here's the relevant code:

```
blobs = bucket.list(Storage.BlobListOption.prefix(sourcePath),
                    Storage.BlobListOption.currentDirectory());
for (Blob blob : blobs.iterateAll()) {
    // ...
    Long updateTime = blob.getUpdateTime();
    Long createTime = blob.getCreateTime();
    // ==> updateTime, createTime are null, blob.isDirectory() is true
}
```

For "normal files", `isDirectory` is false, and there are non-null `updateTime`s and non-null `createTime`s.  How can I get the `updateTime` for a directory object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [client library doc](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-storage/latest/com/google/cloud/storage/Blob.html), The class `Blob` has has a parent class called `BlobInfo` and the subclass has inherited a method called [`getUpdateTime()`](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-storage/latest/com/google/cloud/storage/BlobInfo.html#getUpdateTime--). As described:

> **getUpdateTime()** Returns the last modification time of the blob's metadata expressed as the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch.

Therefore, this method is not intended for what you're trying to use it for. It's meant for checking the time when the object's metadata is updated.

And as @Guillaume mentioned, in a storage bucket, you don't really "update" files because [objects are immutable](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/key-terms#immutability) (but object metadata [varies](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata)). Under the hood, objects are deleted and replaced with a new one whenever you "update" it.

So, the solution is to use [`getCreateTime()`](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-storage/latest/com/google/cloud/storage/BlobInfo.html#getCreateTime--) to see when the object was last created/replaced.

---

**UPDATE**:

The root cause on why you're seeing null is because of `Storage.BlobListOption.currentDirectory()`. As per doc:

> If specified, results are returned in a directory-like mode. Blobs whose names, after a possible prefix(String), do not contain the '/' delimiter are returned as is. Blobs whose names, after a possible prefix(String), contain the '/' delimiter, will have their name truncated after the delimiter and **will be returned as Blob objects where only BlobInfo.getBlobId(), BlobInfo.getSize() and BlobInfo.isDirectory() are set**.

A solution is to remove `Storage.BlobListOption.currentDirectory()`. Or you can use this code to get a specific directory. It will work even if the directory is empty but `isDirectory()` will always return false:

```
Blob blob = storage.get(bucketName, sourcePath, Storage.BlobGetOption.fields(Storage.BlobField.values()));
System.out.println("Bucket: " + blob.getBucket());
System.out.println("Name: " + blob.getName());
System.out.println("TimeCreated: " + new Date(blob.getCreateTime()));
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Unfortunately, getCreateTime() also returns null.  I've updated my question to say so.  It's odd, for "normal files", the createTimes and updateTimes exist and are identical.  For directories (which are really just empty files), they are null in Java, but populated and identical in the gsutil results.

Comment: @kc2001 I've updated my answer, please check and let me know if this is what you need

Comment: To add explanation on my post, both are identical at first but updateTimes will change if you update or configure a metadata on an object. To see for yourself, run this command to set a custom metadata on an object: `gsutil setmeta -h "x-goog-meta-dogbreed:doge" gs://mybucket/Dir2/`

Answer (score 1):

Directory doesn't exist on Cloud Storage. Ok ok, it's difficult to accept, let me explain! A storage bucket is a bucket and you put all the object at the root path of the bucket. The object name can contain / and, on the UI the object that have the same prefix, separated by / are grouped together.

You can have a try!! put a file in your bucket `gs://myBucket/dir/myObject.txt` you can see a directory on the UI. Remove your object, the directory disappear. It's only a part of the object path!

For this same reason, you can only search by prefix and not by suffix.

so, now, why, on the UI you can create a folder? Just because some customer ask for this!! but now, have a closer look to your directory. perform a `gsutil ls -L gs://mybucket/Dir2/`

You should see this

```
gs://mybucket/Dir2/:
    Creation time:          Thu, 11 Feb 2021 22:32:36 GMT
    Update time:            Thu, 11 Feb 2021 22:32:36 GMT
    Storage class:          STANDARD
    Content-Length:         0
    Content-Type:           text/plain
    Hash (crc32c):          AAAAAA==
    Hash (md5):             1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg==
    ETag:                   CIL1r8Xx4u4CEAE=
    Generation:             1613082756119170
    Metageneration:         1
    ACL:                    []
TOTAL: 1 objects, 0 bytes (0 B)
```

What do it mean? You have a file, of size 0, with a name empty "". It's simply a hack found by Google to create a directory: create an empty and invisible file (no name)!

Remove it, the directory disappear, as before! No magic!

---

Go back to your question. Now that you know the directory not exist, try to print the name, the generation and to see what happens. To see the isDirectory to true is "scaring". If it's really the 0 bytes file that the Google Cloud Storage library return as directory object is a big mistake!

In addition, because I already blow your mind on storage I can continue: you can't update an object in Cloud Storage. Only create, delete, read. No move, no rename! (Yes also action possible on the UI, and even is some libraries...). The 2 last actions copy the blob with the new path (path = name, so no move, it's a full new path=new object) and then delete the previous one. And also same thing when you change of storage class.

All of this to say the updateTime is also a mistake!!

*I haven't this in Python (only create and delete time, no boolean to indicate if a directory or not).*

So be careful to the Java library with what you know now!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I tried using createTime instead of updateTime, but got the same null results.  (I've updated the question to say so.)  Since "directories" are really just files, I'm surprised to experience different behavior regarding the times.