# List blobs in a directory on Google Cloud Storage returns wrong result

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

I want to list all blobs in a directory on Google Cloud Storage like this:

```
  public List<Blob> getFiles(String bucketName, String path) {

    final Storage storage = storageSupplier.get();

    final Page<Blob> blobs =
        storage.list(
            bucketName,
            BlobListOption.currentDirectory(),
            BlobListOption.prefix((path.endsWith("/") ? path : (path + "/"))));
    final Iterator<Blob> blobIterator = blobs.iterateAll().iterator();
    final List<Blob> files = new ArrayList<>();
    while (blobIterator.hasNext()) {
      Blob blob = blobIterator.next();
      System.out.println(blob.getName() + ", isDirectory: " + blob.isDirectory());
      if (!blob.isDirectory()) {
        files.add(blob);
      }
    }
    return files;
  }
```

In my bucket I have a directory called `input` and I'm calling the method above with my bucket name and a path = `input/`.
In logs I get:

```
input/, isDirectory: false
input/1.json, isDirectory: false
input/2.json, isDirectory: false
input/3.json, isDirectory: false
```

There are 2 problems I see:

The `input` directory is on the list. This I can understand as it also contains the `prefix` set in a `list(...)` method call.

But **my question** is: why the `isDirectory()` returns false for `input` blob as it is clearly a directory?

Documentation of `isDirectory()` method stays:

> Returns true if the current blob represents a directory. This can only happen if the blob is returned by Storage.list(String, Storage.BlobListOption) when the Storage.BlobListOption.currentDirectory() option is used. [...]

Version of my Google Cloud Storage client:
`com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:1.113.9`

Answer (score 3):

I already [answered a similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66161833/how-to-get-the-updatetime-for-a-directory-blob-using-the-gcs-java-apis/66164279#66164279)

TL;DR: it's a big mistake to look for directories in a platform that doesn't have directory!

IMO, it's a mistake made by the Java Client Library developers.

So, don't rely on directory indicator. Understand the underlying platform and use it wisely.

Comment: "Understand the underlying platform and use it wisely." - I disagree. In GCStorage there isa button "create dir", the same UI organizes blobs in a directory-based structure, Java (and other clients) has "isDirectory" method, etc. Is it covered by "understand the platform"? So Google everywhere presents it as "directory" but somehow it's a user/developer who needs to understand it? Please

Comment: Users want to have a similar experience than with a file system, but it's not a file system. It's a mistake from Google to "lie" like this! Try a move of 1Million file in linux and on GCS, it's not the same. It looks like a file system but it doesn't, it's a blob storage. If you have an engine, 4 wheels and 1 steering wheel, you won't go on the highway if it's a tractor! But it looks like to a car.

Answer (score 0):

isDirectory() adds the parent folder in the result
so if you don't have any other nested folder for the one which you want a list of then you can try this:

```
    public List<String> getListOfFilenamesInDirectory(String bucketName, String gcsFolderPath) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Page<Blob> blobs = storage.list(bucketName, Storage.BlobListOption.currentDirectory(), Storage.BlobListOption.prefix(gcsFolderPath));
    Iterable<Blob> blobIterator = blobs.iterateAll();
    for (Blob b : blobIterator) {
      String fileName = b.getName();
//      b.isDirectory() is giving wrong results
      if (!fileName.endsWith("/")) {
        list.add(fileName);
      }
    }
    return list;
  }
```

Comment: a file name cannot end with / ?