# How to list all the files present under some folder in Google Cloud Storage in Java

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to read all the files present under given folder and bucket in google cloud storage.

```
Bucket bucket = storage.get("BucketName");
        Page<Blob> object = bucket.list();
        //Page<Bucket> buckets = storage.list();
        for (Blob no : object.iterateAll()) {
            System.out.println(no.toString());
        }
```

In the above code, I was able to list all the files present under a bucket named "BucketName". But I want to list the files present under the given folder/path, not the entire bucket.

Example:
gs://BucketName/Random/Test/sample1.csv
gs://BucketName/Random/Test/sample2.csv
gs://BucketName/Random/Test/sample3.csv

So here I want to list all the files present under path Random/Test/ and bucket named BucketName.

Can someone please help here?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Page<Blob> blobs =
        storage.list(
            bucketName,
            Storage.BlobListOption.prefix(directoryPrefix),
            Storage.BlobListOption.currentDirectory());

    for (Blob blob : blobs.iterateAll()) {
      System.out.println(blob.getName());
    }
```

For detailed explanation go through the documentation : https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-list-files-with-prefix

Comment: For me this only prints the directories not the files in them.

Comment: Need a little tweak like this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75108637/4827151